# discuss "stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:withString:"

Tags: objective-c, nsstring

I am thinking about some details regarding

stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:withString: in NSString class

According to document.

It returns a new string in which all occurrences of a target string in the receiver are replaced by another given string.

```
- (NSString *)stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:(NSString *)target withString:(NSString *)replacement
```

Parameters
target
The string to replace.
replacement
The string with which to replace target.

my question is that if the replacement string is not found in the target string. If there would be some side effects to call this function.

Thanks

For example

```
    NSString *myString = [NSString stringWithString:@"Hello my string"];
    NSString *myReplacementString = [myString stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"NOTFOUND" withString@"Any side effect?"];
    NSLog(@"my replacement string is %@", myReplacementString);
```

Comment: What do you mean by side effects? Change of the string?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are no side effects: if the substring to be replaced doesn't occur in the original string, you end up with an `NSString` identical to the one you started with.

Indeed, (this is an implementation detail and you shouldn't depend on it, but) you don't even end up with a copy of the original string, but a pointer to the same exact string.

Answer (score 2):

That function has no side effects, and if the search string isn't found in the receiver, the receiver will be returned unaltered.

Answer (score 1):

1. `myString`, `target` and `replacement` aren't modified whether a match if found or not:

   - The method doesn't change the string `myString` in place but creates a new string that will contain the result.
   - `target` and `replacement` are parameters of the method and their values don't get changed.
   - `myString`, `target` and `replacement` are immutable strings.
2. There are no errors or exceptions if no match is found.